# Spnego auth not working for response code driven http client

Tags: http, kerberos, spnego

I am trying to write a http client which connects to a kerberos enabled tomcat(tested to be correct using browsers). It first gets the response code (which will be 401) and as according continue with its work.

The code is

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.*;

public class SampleHTTP2 {

    static final String kuser = "correctusername"; // your account name
    static final String kpass = "correctpassword"; // your password for the account

    static class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            //System.out.println("I am reaching here");
            // I haven't checked getRequestingScheme() here, since for NTLM
            // and Negotiate, the username and password are all the same.
            System.err.println("Feeding username and password for "
               + getRequestingScheme());
            return (new PasswordAuthentication(kuser, kpass.toCharArray()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL url = new URL("http://mycompname:6008/examples/");
        HttpURLConnection h1 = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        int rescode = h1.getResponseCode();

        System.out.println(rescode);
        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "C:\\login2.conf");
        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");

        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "C:\\krb5.ini");
        if(rescode == 401){     
            Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());

            URL url2 = new URL("http://mycompname/examples/");
            URLConnection h2 = url2.openConnection();
            InputStream ins2 = h2.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins2));
            String str;
            while((str = reader.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when i comment the line:-

```
 int rescode = h1.getResponseCode();
```

and put if(true) instead of if(rescode ==401), it works.

I am not sure what is going wrong. getResponseCode() internally calls getinputStream and thus I have used a separate url connection. Even still it does not work

P.S - Server is perfectly set up and the Authenticator class is also correct.